# How to return specific rows that meets certain conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am totally new in SQL. I was working on a query that should return specific rows only from a table.
(see. example source table and desired output below). can somebody help me figure out this one? I've tried searching through related topics on iterating through rows but was unsuccessful to find the answer I sought. thanks.

Sample table

```
Machine   Station   Defect Code CreateTime
1         LU        f1          8/20/2013 7:07
1         LU        f2          8/20/2013 7:07
1         SLC       d1          8/20/2013 7:08
1         SLC       d2          8/20/2013 7:09
1         SLC       d3          8/20/2013 7:10
1         SLC       d1          8/20/2013 7:10
1         SLC       d2          8/20/2013 7:11
1         SLC       d1          8/20/2013 7:17
1         SLC       d1          8/20/2013 7:20
1         UL        f3          8/20/2013 7:26
1         UL        f4          8/20/2013 7:26
1         UL        f3          8/20/2013 7:26
1         UL        f4          8/20/2013 7:26
2         LU        f2          8/20/2013 7:29
2         SLC       d1          8/20/2013 7:31
2         SLC       d1          8/20/2013 7:38
2         SLC       d2          8/20/2013 7:38
2         SLC       d3          8/20/2013 7:39
2         SLC       d2          8/20/2013 7:39
2         SLC       d4          8/20/2013 7:39
2         SLC       d5          8/20/2013 7:42
2         SLC       d1          8/20/2013 7:43
2         SLC       d1          8/20/2013 7:52
2         SLC       d1          8/20/2013 7:53
2         SLC       d2          8/20/2013 7:53
2         SLC       d2          8/20/2013 7:54
2         SLC       d4          8/20/2013 7:55
2         SLC       d5          8/20/2013 7:56
```

Needed result:

OCAP Triggered on Machine1. d1 multiple occurence

```
Machine Station Defect Code CreateTime
1       SLC     d1          8/20/2013 7:08
1       SLC     d1          8/20/2013 7:10
1       SLC     d1          8/20/2013 7:17
1       SLC     d1          8/20/2013 7:20
```

OCAP Triggered on Machine1. d1 consecutive occurence

```
Machine Station Defect Code CreateTime
1       SLC     d1          8/20/2013 7:17
1       SLC     d1          8/20/2013 7:20
```

OCAP Triggered on Machine 2. d1 consecutive occurence

```
Machine Station Defect Code CreateTime
2       SLC     d1          8/20/2013 7:31
2       SLC     d1          8/20/2013 7:38
```

OCAP Triggered on Machine 2. d2 multiple occurence

```
Machine Station Defect Code CreateTime
2       SLC     d2          8/20/2013 7:38
2       SLC     d2          8/20/2013 7:39
2       SLC     d2          8/20/2013 7:53
```

Comment: Your requirement can only be met by using stored procedures if you want to do this on SQL level. On that approach I cannot give any useful codes since I'm not so experianced with it. But the same thing can be done by writing some code on php or .net or java or any other sql supported language, whichever you're most familiar with.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen I don't see why you couldn't do this with SQL. Also, I updated my answer with a SQL Fiddle example (and some fixes to the query based on that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple occurences would be the easiest. You count how many of each combination you can find and select those with a count bigger than 3.

```
SELECT S.Machine,
       S.Station,
       S.DefectCode,
       S.CreateTime
FROM ( SELECT Machine,
              Station,
              DefectCode,
              CreateTime,
              COUNT(CreateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Machine, Station, DefectCode) AS DefectCount
       FROM SAMPLE
       WHERE Machine = :machine ) S
WHERE S.DefectCount > 3
```

Consecutive occurence is a bit harder (the following query may not be the most optimal one). Assuming consecutive is 'consecutive date', you could try the following:

```
WITH OrderedSample
AS ( SELECT Machine,
            Station,
            DefectCode,
            CreateTime,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreateTime) AS RowNr
     FROM SAMPLE
     WHERE Machine = :machine )

SELECT Current.Machine,
       Current.Station,
       Current.DefectCode,
       Current.CreateTime
FROM OrderedSample Current
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM OrderedSample Next
               WHERE Current.Machine = Next.Machine
               AND   Current.Station = Next.Station
               AND   Current.DefectCode = Next.DefectCode
               AND   Current.RowNr = Next.RowNr - 1 )
OR    EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM OrderedSample Prev
               WHERE Current.Machine = Prev.Machine
               AND   Current.Station = Prev.Station
               AND   Current.DefectCode = Prev.DefectCode
               AND   Current.RowNr = Prev.RowNr + 1 )
```

**EDIT**

Just realized the second query becomes a bit easier because you are working with a fixed Machine:

```
WITH OrderedSample
AS ( SELECT Machine,
            Station,
            DefectCode,
            CreateTime,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreateTime) AS RowNr
     FROM SAMPLE
     WHERE Machine = :machine )

SELECT Curr.Machine,
       Curr.Station,
       Curr.DefectCode,
       Curr.CreateTime, RowNr
FROM OrderedSample Curr
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM OrderedSample Next
               WHERE Curr.Station = Next.Station
               AND   Curr.DefectCode = Next.DefectCode
               AND   Curr.RowNr = Next.RowNr - 1 )
OR    EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM OrderedSample Prev
               WHERE Curr.Station = Prev.Station
               AND   Curr.DefectCode = Prev.DefectCode
               AND   Curr.RowNr = Prev.RowNr + 1 )
```

**EDIT 2**: Just noticed Machine & Station are two columns, edited

**EDIT 3**: Some fixes based on [Sql Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50b92/31)

Comment: thanks sam! this code is awesome. but is there a way not to enumerate the machine numbers? cause if i have 100 machines i have to paste the code hundred times. also how do put it in the email body arrange exactly as the above expected result? "OCAP triggered on machine 1. d1 consecutive occurence" then the resulting query for that paricular machine. is it possible using Database mail? I've read that queries result can be included in the email body but cannot quite figure out how to do it. hope you can help me out while your at it. thanks!

Comment: @L42 If you are happy with a list of everything in one table, then for multiple occurences you only need to remove the `WHERE` that filters on machines, the same for consecutive occurence (but take the first one of the two examples as you will now need to join on Machine as well in your `EXISTS`). If you want a seperate list for each Machine/DefectCode combination things get a lot more complicated as you'll need to loop over everything somehow (either in an application or in a stored procedure as Tolga commented). I'm not familiar with Database mail, so no idea how to handle that.

Comment: yep a list in one table will do but i have to output the comments on what particular machine and what particular defect the OCAP was triggered which will still complicate things (this will serve as alert notice when a certain defect repeatedly occurs). btw, no worries on DB mail man. you've helped me more than enough with these codes.